# Which one is the last tile?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

This one is a little different than the IQ test type questions you may have seen before.

Which one of the bottom 4 tiles can complete the pattern? Why?

[image]

Ignore the EXCEL background.

HINT

> All RED DOTS are assigned a meaningful letter

Comment: Hmmm. I was looking for the first letter of spectral lines of Hydrogen, but nope, probably not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess:

> 4

The red letters represent

> countries
>  P - Portugal
>  S - Spain
>  F - France
>  B - Belgium

The red dot with the black letter represent

> capitals with the rough location inside the country
>  L - Lisbon
>  M - Madrid
>  P - Paris
>  B - Brussels

Which leads to

> Germany with capital Berlin as the answer. While Netherlands (2) also lies east of Belgium, the capital Amsterdam is not on the east border. The other possible answers are:
>  1 - Switzerland (Bern)
>  3 - Italy (Rome).

Comment: On a lighter note, cannot **I** and **R** point to Iceland and Reykjavik( (option 3)?

Answer (score -1):

Well, w |'s answer has got it nailed, based on which I guess

> it could be 2 (**N**etherlands and **A**msterdam)

As,

> the path of traversal of the countries **+** capitals is heading towards NorthEast and hence Germany + Berlin can be safely ruled out.